# Python autoindenting in vim

Tags: python, vim, neovim

Basically, when I'm working with python in vim and exit the indentation of a function, I would press enter and vim would automatically take me back to the same indentation. See the gif below for a visual of what I mean.

[image]

I've tried to disable the smart and auto-indent feature in my config file.

Comment: Have you tried disabling smartindent with `:set nosmartindent`?

Comment: Yeah I have, no luck there. Also tried with `:set noautoindent`

Comment: The problem with Python is that there is no "end of block" indication. So, it isn't possibly to determine if you simply want an empty line after print and continue inside the for or of its contents ended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this:

[image: Gif of indentation of test code on my computer]

Add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
set nu
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set smartindent
set showmatch
set incsearch
```